# Report Designer - Nest IIF inside a Sum with multiple datasets

Tags: reporting-services

While there are many code samples for the individual pieces of this question, as a neophyte with Report Designer, I cannot get the syntax for this correct.

I have a textfield that I want to display a SUM of "Held Hours" from one of three DataSets, and this is determined by another field in that same DataSet having a value of "H."

So taking it in pieces, this works to sum ALL hours in ReportDataset.

```
=Sum((Fields!RegHrs.Value + Fields!OvtHrs.Value),"ReportDataset")
```

Now, somehow i need to nest that in an IIF.  I need that SUM expression to be the "True" return from the IIF when the BillStatus = "H."

```
IIF(Fields!BillStatus.Value = "H",true,false)
```

I cannot seem to figure out how to combine the IIF and the SUM so that they pull from "ReportDataset" and are syntactically correct.

I've been trying various permutations of this:

```
=Sum(IIF(Fields!BillStatus.Value = "H",((Fields!RegHrs.Value + Fields!OvtHrs.Value),"ReportDataset"),0))
```

Any pointers?

---

New Info:

The following reports as syntactically correct, but gives me 0 for a return value.

```
=Sum(IIF(Fields!BillStatus.Value = "H", (Fields!RegHrs.Value + Fields!OvtHrs.Value),0),"ReportDataset")
```

There should be hundreds of hours returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a nested sum:

```
=Sum(IIF(Fields!BillStatus.Value = "H", Sum(Fields!RegHrs.Value + Fields!OvtHrs.Value,"ReportDataset"),0),"ReportDataset")
```

Or:

```
=IIF(Fields!BillStatus.Value = "H", Sum(Fields!RegHrs.Value + Fields!OvtHrs.Value,"ReportDataset"),0)
```

Comment: Whoa! Excellent.  The second option is giving me values.  I'm not sure why, but I'll run with it.  Now, I don't know if my values are correct, but I'm GETTING them, and at least now I can massage my query to get accurate information.  Thanks glh.  I appreciate the response.

Comment: Follow Up: To get this to work, I had to convert my return values. At the moment I'm using CDec(Fields!RegAmt.Value), etc. It's giving me four decimal places, and I don't see the option to limit that to two.  How is that done?

Comment: Solved!  If I do the following in my query to build the dataset, the two decimal places are respected in the report itself.
    cast(RegHrs as numeric(10,2)) as 'RegHrs',
    cast(OvtHrs as numeric(10,2)) as 'OvtHrs',

Comment: I'm glad I was able to point you. You'll be able to set the fields numeric display in its properties saving you doing it in the query.

Answer (score 1):

Can you do it in your dataset using SQL? If so, just use the following:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN BillStatus = 'H' THEN RegHrs + OvtHrs END AS HeldHours
FROM MyTable
```

Then all you need to do is sum this field:

```
=Sum(Fields!HeldHours.Value, "ReportDataSet")
```

Comment: Chris, remembering that I'm new to Report Designer, this question may not seem as inane What is the best practice regarding DataSets?  I've been told that I want as few as possible, so I've constructed "ReportDataset" to house everything I could imagine wanting for this report.  I'm finding it difficult to query my DataSet from the report.  I'm inclined to want to treat it as a table, but find that doesn't work. (Continued)

Comment: I can't "Select from" my DataSet.  What I take you to mean above is to create multiple DataSets, each with its own unique look at the data; one for Held Hours, another for Billable, a third for NonLabor revenue, etc.  I sense you know something about this Report Designer.  What's the best practice here?